# How to prevent my ball going through my bowl wit a trigger?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image][image]
Hi guys, So i have this bowl (i made in blender), and a ball inside it. My bowl has mesh collider, convex and trigger, as well rigidbody . I know if the bowl is on trigger the ball can go right through. But the thing is i need the trigger on the bowl so my claw can grab it and pull it. The ball keeps going down through my bowl. Is there a way to have my ball in the bowl without going through the bowl with a trigger.
Btw even if the bowl isnt on trigger the ball still goings through and the ball is not on trigger. please help! Im desperate :( I just need this to work .

Comment: Can your claw not have the trigger and make the bowl have a normal collider?

Comment: well, it needs the trigger to grab my bowl. When I take the trigger off the claw it doesnt grab it anymore.

Comment: What I mean is for `OnTriggerEnter` etc only **one** of the two needs to be a trigger => if the claw has it then everything can collide as usual, only the claw can pass through things and grab them

Comment: I did what you said but regardless the ball still falls through. :/

Answer (score 1):

Can your claw not have the trigger and make the bowl have a normal collider?

The alternative would probably be

- create a child object of the bowl
- attach a `MeshCollider`
- assign the very same mesh of the bowl to this new collider
- make this one a normal "non-trigger"
- assign your original bowl a new layer like e.g. `Grabable` (but no to the child)
- assign your claw a new layer e.g. `Grab`

And finally adjust the physics settings -> Collision Layer Matrix so that

- Grab **only** collides with Gravable
- Grabable **only** collides with Grab

This way your claw can only interact with those things set on the `Grabable` layer while everything else can collide between each others.

You could consider though to not use `MeshCollider` (which is of course expensive) but rather simple `Sphere`/`Capsule`/`BoxCollider` according to the objects forms since the trigger doesn't need to be absolutely exact I assume

Comment: Would you mind going on chat and helping me out ?

Comment: So you can see my code. I just cant make a chat yet bc i dont have 100 reputation . if you can help ill appreciate it.